# I want to change background color and text color when I hover on background

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover on card Background I want to change Background color and text color. How can I do this ? Please help

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far, it helps us to help you.

Comment: I am trying to upload my code. But it shows some error on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

you should use the pseudo class `:hover`

```
.card {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it isn't working

Comment: Can you provide a code example ?

Comment: Poppoff I am trying to upload the code but it isn't allowing me to upload Please help

Comment: Edit your first post and copy/past your code

Comment: I am trying but it isn't working